# Shortcut to array accessing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Okay, so I'm writing a stock control program in Visual Studio 2010.  I'm storing product codes and quantities for each location as ints in List type arrays.  The problem is, I'm going to use it to track the stock levels in 500 or so different locations.  The user inputs the location they want to view, and it gets displayed as a pop-up box on the screen.  How can I do this without using 500 if (location == A00) type statements?

Comment: Are you looking for `std::map`, by any chance?

Comment: I need to store multiple values at each location, doesn't an std map only allow one value per key?

Comment: Yes, but said value can be of an arbitrarily complex class type.

Comment: So you could have an STD map of lists?

Comment: Yes, you could have, for example, a `std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string> >` if you are so inclined.